# are questions about programs features on-topic

Tags: support

I have a program which mentioned having a feature that's simply not working, is this considered on-topic for this site ? if not what stackexchange site suits it better ?

The program is monodevelop And code completion doesn't seem to work in c++ on linux mint(this is for clarification only so don't answer it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine to ask here on Super User, but before you ask:

- Collect the **version** information for your OS (Linux Mint) and Monodevelop, and include it in your question. Very important!
- Tell us how you *installed* MonoDevelop, including the exact steps, and if you downloaded packages from a repo, whether it was the standard Linux Mint repo or a custom one.
- Tell us exactly what doesn't work, and provide screenshots if possible.
- If possible, provide a reference to somewhere that suggests that this feature should be available for C++ specifically.
- Tell us what you've tried to fix it.
- Tell us whether you've upgraded Linux Mint or Monodevelop from one version to another without reinstalling
- Tell us whether you've tried deleting your monodevelop user directory (not sure exactly what it would be, but the logical choice would be `~/.monodevelop` or something similar).

We need: **details, details, details**, and **what you've tried** in order for this to be a good question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go and post the details, I might try some things first because I haven't tried many things to fix it